# create bind volumes with docker compose v2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to create volumes using docker compose.
I've listed all volumes in a yaml file `volumes.yaml`:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  a_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/opt/volumes/a_volume"
    name: "a_volume"

  b_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/opt/volumes/b_volume"
    name: "b_volume"
```

Then using docker-compose v1 (1.29.0) I can create all volumes this way:

```
docker-compose -f volumes.yaml up
Creating volume "a_volume" with local driver
Creating volume "b_volume" with local driver
Attaching to
```

Using docker-compose v2 (2.5.0) I don't know how to do it, the command has no effect:

```
docker compose -f volumes.yaml up
no service selected
```

**UPDATE:**

Define a dummy service like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  dummy:
    image: rwgrim/docker-noop
    volumes:
      - a_volume:/tmp
      - b_volume:/tmp

volumes:
  a_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/opt/volumes/a_volume"
    name: "a_volume"

  b_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "/opt/volumes/b_volume"
    name: "b_volume"
```

**[docker-noop](https://hub.docker.com/r/rwgrim/docker-noop)** simply doesn't do anything (no operation).
Volumes will be created using docker compose up command.

Comment: Same output with docker compose v2.10.2.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes @Rutuja. I solved defining a dummy service using the rwgrim/docker-noop image, see post update